# Goodies for colored french accents

Tags: fonts, context, french

I save this font file as example :

```tex
-- file pagella.lfg
return {
    name = "pagella",
    comment = "Goodies that complement pagella.",
    colorschemes = {
        default = {
            [1] = {
                0x0301, 0x0300, 0x0302, 0x0308, 0x0323,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

To get colored accents.

But I have no result. What is missing ?

```tex
\input pagella.lfg
\mainlanguage[fr]
\setupcolors[state=start]
\definefontfeature
  [pagella]
  [goodies=pagella,
   colorscheme=default,
  ,protrusion=quality,expansion=quality] 
\definecolor[colorscheme:1:1][r=1,g=0.3]


%%%%%%%%%%%%
\starttext
%%%%%%%%%%%%

Un texte avant, non coloré.

\setfontcolorscheme [1]    élève  pâtes gîte site

\stoptext
```

Comment: Ah! I copy  paste wrong  unicodes ! 

Comment: @DG' They’re both Greek and French. They will not, however, apply to precomposed characters, unless you normalize to NFD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a bit tricky because ConTeXt is dealing with precomposed characters. A solution would be to manually apply a split for accented characters into non accented characters and [combining diacritical marks (Unicode range 0300–036F)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf). [Here's a list of other types of features you can define in ConTeXt](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg80290.html) . Then you color combining marks so you get the desired effect.

Btw I've just considered some random examples for lowercase letters. It's up to you to extend the list of characters to convert.

**Caveats:** With respect to `i`: when include cases for this letter, use the dotless form `ı` instead (U+0131). Otherwise your diacritics will be wrongly placed. Also, I haven't included `i` because it will mess up ligatures as `fi` and `ffi`, but nothing prevents you from doing it (but please don't).

```lua
--Save this in the same folder as your main file
--coloredaccents.lfg
return {
    name = "coloredaccents",
    version = "2021/02/09",
    comment = "Colored accents for French",
    author  = "Jairo A. del Rio",
    colorschemes = {
        default = {
            { "0x0300:0x036F" }, -- Combining Diacritical Marks
        }
    }
}
```

```
%%%For testing only
\setuppapersize[A6,landscape]
%%%
\mainlanguage[fr]
\setupbodyfont[pagella]
\startluacode
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "coloredaccents",
        type = "multiple",
        data = {
                    ["à"] = {"a","̀"},
                    ["â"] = {"a","̂"},
                    ["è"] = {"e","̀"},
                    ["é"] = {"e","́"},
                    ["ê"] = {"e","̂"},
                    ["ë"] = {"e","̈"},
                    ["î"] = {"ı","̂"},
                    ["ï"] = {"ı","̈"},
                    ["ô"] = {"o","̂"},
                    ["ö"] = {"o","̈"},
                    ["ù"] = {"u","̀"},
                    ["û"] = {"u","̂"},
                    ["ü"] = {"u","̈"},
                    --Add more if required
        }
    }
\stopluacode
\definefontfeature[coloredaccents][default]
    [coloredaccents=yes,goodies=coloredaccents,colorscheme=default]
\definecolor[colorscheme:1:1][r=1,g=0.3]
%%%Remove "@30pt" for a normal font size
\definefont[nice][Serif*coloredaccents @ 30pt]
%%%
\starttext
\setfontcolorscheme[1]%
{\nice
planète écouter à où 

château fête côté sûr 

dîner naïve Noël

%I know Göttingen is German, but it looks cool here.
Archélaüs Göttingen}
\stoptext
```

[image]